# Why does Javascript cast null to string at variable assignment?

Tags: javascript

In Firefox 45 *on OSX*, when I fetch an item from `localStorage` from a key that does not exist, the function call returns `null`. I tested this in the console.

If I instead assign the call result to a variable, and print its value in the console, I get `"null"`, i.e. a string.

Why does a variable assignment of a previously not defined variable cast a call result to a String?

Used code (in the console):

```
localStorage.getItem("non-existing-key"); // returns null

var x = localStorage.getItem("non-existing-key");
x // returns "null"
```

Edit: both versions seem to behave correctly on Chrome 50.0.2661.86 on OSX (both return `null`)

Edit2: my mistake. I used another variable name in my tests (specifically: `var name`). Now, if I let the console return the value of the variable `name`, it returns `window.name`, which is a property of `window` of the type String, defaulting to `"null"`. So, it's not an assignment that causes a cast, but instead its that I got a String property defined by `window`.

Comment: firefox 45.0.2 on windows, cannot reproduce:

localStorage.getItem("non-existing-key"); // returns null
var x = localStorage.getItem("non-existing-key");
x // --> returns null not "null"

Comment: What does it return in other browser ? I reckon you are confused between `null` and `"null"`

Comment: Both versions behave the same on Chrome 50 on OSX by returning `null`, but I had at least one instance where Firefox 45 on Win7 returned "null" as String after the assignment yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. The specific code I used was the following:

```
var name = localStorage.getItem("non-existing-key");
name
```

Now, `getItem` does return `null` and not a String. What then happens is that by letting the console print the value of `name` it does in fact get `window.name` (see [window.name on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)), which by default is `"null"` (a String).